# Adding child node to parent in TreeView WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm starting WPF (this is important note).

I want to fill a tree view with a collection, and if the collection contains specific item I add child node to it (static):

```
private void FillControlTree()
{
    var oClsModule = new ClsModules();
    var allModules = oClsModule.GetData().Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.ModuleCode != 1);
    trvItemGroup.ItemsSource = allModules.ToList();
    foreach (var item in trvItemGroup.Items)
    {
        if (((TbModules)item).ModuleEName.Trim() == "Account")
        {
            ((TreeViewItem)item).Items.Add("Sub Account");
        }
    }
}
```

it throws casting error when casting to `TreeViewItem` :

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   XERP.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.TbModules_9677CFC546FFEF17BF70AEE61B6C8974A095496441FF7FE64C69C77F6B0FE288'
>   to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items property in your TreeView contains collection of TbModules objects. So you cannot cast this object to TreeViewItem. Try this:

```
foreach (TbModules item in trvItemGroup.Items)
{
     if (item.ModuleEName.Trim() == "Account")
     {
          TreeViewItem treeViewItem = (TreeViewItem)trvItemGroup.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
          treeViewItem.Items.Add("Sub Account");
     }
}
```

**EDIT**: ContainerFromItem method will return null, if you call it in window constructor, since window is not loaded yet. Try the following:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindowOnLoaded;
    }

    private void MainWindowOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= MainWindowOnLoaded;
        FillControlTree();
    }
```

Comment: `treeViewItem` is null

Comment: Where do you call the FillControlTree method?

Comment: in the constructor

Comment: So,I move this code to the `MainWindowOnLoaded` from `FillControlTree` ?

Comment: No, just call FillControlTree from MainWindowOnLoaded.

Comment: Great, it works, but do have an idea why the title "Sub account" not showing, instead of empty string?

Comment: this solve it `treeViewItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = "Dubb" });`